# How can I remove characters from message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I would like to take a command that takes in an input from the user let's say `".result 123"` with .result being the bot command and only writing out the string after it. I've tried regex but haven't been successful. This is the code I tried:

Note: Some variables are for me to check the time for when the command is still valid.

```
let userinput = new RegExp('.+');
if(message.content === ".result" + userinput) {
    
    function removeCharacters() {
      message.content = str;
      str = str.substr(8);
      console.log(str); 
    }

    if ((currseconds - seconds) <= 1200) {
      message.channel.send('**FINAL RECORDED FPM:**');
      removeCharacters();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong

- You are declaring a function inside the if, that is a bit weird
- You need to escape a dot in regex,

To find 123 in `.result 123` you could do

```js
const message = { "content": ".result 123" } // test message for this script
const userInput = message.content.match(/\.result (\w+)/)
if (userInput) console.log(userInput[1]); // contains the command
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `.split('.result ')` in javascript then you will get an array of leftover [mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). For your case -

```js
const input = '.result 1243523'

const splitted = input.split('.result ') // In split the text you want to remove.

// got an array of left over selecting text after your `.result ` removed
const result = splitted[1]

console.log(result) // 1243523
```